# PHP UTF-8 file_put_contents

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents

I would like UTF-8 HTML file in PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents ( 'http://google.com/' );
file_put_contents ( 'utf8.html', $html );
// Is not UTF-8. It is ISO-8859-1. I would like UTF-8.
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you determine it's not UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below

```
$html = file_get_contents ('http://google.com/' ); 
file_put_contents('utf8.html', utf8_encode($html));
```